# Get Akeneo PIM product as standard format in own bundle

Tags: symfony, akeneo

I have a custom symfony bundle used in Akeneo 1.6 (Upgraded from 1.3 some time ago), which I need to port to Akeneo 2.2.

What I need is get all product data by product ID in a controller action.
This was done by **$repository->getFullProduct($productId)**. This Method was removed in the current Akeneo version.

While researching I found that the "standard format" seemed helpful as it contains all product data as array.

*How can I recieve this data?* It doesn't have to be a clean solution, Quick&Dirty (Like the whole Bundle ;) ) is just fine. It's only for internal use.

I tried some stuff like **$productStandard = $this->container->get('pim_api.normalizer.product')->normalize($product);** whith different services, but based on the useless error messages I recieved I think it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

When searching products in Akeneo PIM, you should use the **Product Query Builder**. You can read more about it on [the official documentation on querying products](https://docs.akeneo.com/2.2/manipulate_pim_data/product/query.html). A quite similar question has been asked, you can see my answer here: [Query products with Doctrine ind Akeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762745/query-products-with-doctrine-ind-akeneo).

To get the [standard format of a product](https://docs.akeneo.com/2.2/manipulate_pim_data/product/query.html), you can normalize your `Product` instance with the normalizer.

So this would look like this:

```
<?php
// Get a new instance of the PQB
$pqbFactory = $this->getContainer()->get('pim_catalog.query.product_query_builder_factory');
$pqb = $pqbFactory->create([
    'default_locale' => 'en_US',
    'default_scope' => 'ecommerce'
]);

// Now you can search for products with your ids
$pqb->addFilter(
    'id',
    'IN',
    ['234', '22', '90']
);

// Retrieve your products
$productsCursor = $pqb->execute();
$normalizedProducts = [];
foreach ($productsCursor as $product) {
    // normalize them to the standard format
    $normalizedProducts[] = $this->getContainer()->get('pim_standard_format_serializer')->normalize($product, 'standard');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks very similar to what I tried.
When I try to use the Service like you did in the example I get: "You have requested a non-existent service "pim_standard_format_serializer"

Comment: Instead of `pim_standard_format_serializer`, you can try with `->get('pim_catalog.normalizer.standard.product')->normalize($product, 'standard');`

Comment: Now I get an error I saw before, but don't know what to do with it: "Serializer must be a normalizer"